# failed to load data showing string cant be converted

Tags: android, json

This error occurs when the json tries to fetch the data
org.json.JSONException: Value 505 at error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
   try {

```
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(wsResponseString);


        if (jsonObj.has("error")) {
            JSONObject errorJSObj;
            try {
                errorJSObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("error");
                if (errorJSObj != null) {
                    if (errorJSObj.has("message")) {
                        userBean.setErrorMsg(errorJSObj.optString("message"));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            userBean.setStatus("error");
```

Comment: what is your json string?

Comment: its either 1 or 0

Comment: then it is not a valid json and throwing  an exception